# Remove Contact Actions links (hook_civicrm_summaryActions or CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.tpl)

Tags: developer, menu

What is a correct way of whole Contact Actions menu ( this ones: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cb5hmnb6e ) disable ?

- **hook_civicrm_summaryActions** ( http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_summaryActions  ) doesn't remove whole thing;
- altering templates/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.tpl seems to be a
  bit overwhelming;
- hiding it via CSS doesn't seems like a good idea either.

Comment: If CSS isn't a good idea (I'm curious why?), you could remove it from the DOM with jQuery .remove(), but perhaps a bigger question is why are you trying to hide those actions?  Not wanting certain users to do things?  Is this ultimately a permission issue?

Comment: Thanks Allen;DOM manipulations via CSS/jQuery is good as a "last resort", because, for example, of easy elements "unhide". As for purposes: exactly certain users shouldn't be able to see list of available actions, because it scares them. Ideally it should be two buttons: "View Contact details" / "Add new Member". Can't use permissions unfortunately, since we use Relationships mostly and there are always issues..